# Proof of infinite Cartesian sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

can someone please proof to me why cartesian product of infinite set and finite set = infinite set.
 It's obvious but the proof is unclear to me.

Comment: No, because it's not a true statement as stated.

Comment: why not true? infinite set with a set which is not the empty set.

Comment: Yes, it is true for a *non-empty* finite set.

Comment: Can you please proof that for me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{x_n\}$ and $B=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ be two sets. Let $A\times B$ be the Cartesian product. Consider the subset $A\times \{a_1\}$, notice that $A\times \{a_1\}$ and $A$ has the same carnality. Since $A\times \{a_1\}\subseteq A\times B$, we have $A\times B$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

One way is just to use the definition:Suppose $A$ is infinite and $B\neq \emptyset$. Then,

$A\times B=\left \{ f:\left \{ 1,2 \right \}\to A\cup B\vert f(1)\in A; f(2)\in B \right \}$.

Since $A$ is infinite, and $B$ is non-empty, there are infinitely many choices for $f$.

Comment: A minor typo - I guess you mean $f(2)\in B$, not $=B$.

Comment: yes, I did thanks.